# Getting 'NaN' when I try to read temperatures with DHT11 on ESP8266 with C

Tags: c, arduino, esp8266

[Pictures of the wiring of the DHT11 to the ESP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJSUl.jpg)

When I try to read temperatures in Fahrenheit, Celsius and to get the Humidity, it always says 'nan' on the serial monitor. I'm working the Arduino IDE  with the Generic ESP8266 Module and I got the libraries  "DHT-Sensor-Library" and the "Adafruit-Unified-Sensor"-Library installed.

I know it stands for "Not a number", but why? I looked on here before and tried using (isnan) and store it in a backup-variable, but that didn't work either.

```c
#include <DHT.h>
#include <DHT_U.h>

#define DHT_TYPE  DHT11

#define DHT_PIN   5

#define DHT_POWER 0

DHT dht(DHT_PIN, DHT_TYPE);

const long interval = 2000;

void setup(void) 
{
  pinMode( DHT_POWER, OUTPUT );
  digitalWrite( DHT_POWER, HIGH );

  dht.begin();

  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(500);
  Serial.println("\nDHT running\n");
}

void loop(void)
{
  float h = dht.readHumidity();
  float t = dht.readTemperature();
  float f = dht.readTemperature(true);
  
  Serial.println( "Luftfeuchtigkeit: " + (String)h + " % ");
  Serial.println( "Temperatur      : " + (String)t + " °C");
  Serial.println( "Temperatur      : " + (String)f + " F \n");

  delay(interval);
}
```

Comment: Aside: Not an issue here, but I found, when enabling output, better to set the logic level first and then enable.  Less transients.

Comment: You cannot add strings in C. `"Luftfeuchtigkeit: " + (String)h + " % "` is invalid.

Comment: @pmg I tried removing it but got this error message instead: Arduino: 1.8.13 

dht-server:45:42: error: invalid operands of types 'const char [19]' and 'float' to binary 'operator+'

Comment: I don't know C++, but I think you're using a C++ compiler -- a literal string (like `"Luftfeuchtigkeit: "`) has type `/* readonly */ char [19]` in C; not `const char [19]`.

Comment: I posted the solution as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it:

The code was never made for the ESP8266, it is for the LOLIN (Wemos) D1 R2 & mini, but this was never mentioned in the documents.

Comment: I believe those are all ESP8266 variants.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to power the DHT11 directly from a GPIO pin.
GPIO pins are intended to send signals. When you use them for power, the results can be unpredictable.

Instead, try powering it from one of the "always-on" 3.3V pins.
If that doesn't work, try powering the DHT11 from an external power source (preferably 5V).
If that doesn't work, please post a picture of your circuit.

Comment: Thank you. I tried connecting the VCC-Pin from the DHT11 to the VCC-Pin on the ESP, but that didn't work. I can't connetc it to an external power source because I use the DHT on a breadboard and I don't have the necessary parts with me right now.

Picture will follow.

Comment: Pictures are uploaded and descripted at the top of the original post

Comment: It's a little hard to tell from the angle of the picture, but I think you have the ground connected to the wrong pin.
On the DHT11s I've run into, the power and ground have been on the outermost pins.
Usually you can find the pinout diagram on the back of the DHT11 itself.

Comment: The wiring is okay, I checked that multiple times, but let's get back to powering the DHT11 from a GPIO: When I try to use the Vcc-Pin from the ESP, what is the NodeMCU-name of that pin, because I'm using the NodeMCU-pins all the time (D5 for Data for example)

Comment: I had this table in some of my notes. I'm not 100% sure that is the same for every ESP8266.  
D0: 16, D1: 5, D2: 4, D3: 0, D4: 2, D5: 14, D6: 12, D7: 13, D8: 15, D9: 3, D10: 1

Comment: I posted the solution as an answer